# How to Access Temp Column Alias in Mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to Access temporarily created column
Please see below code example

> Note: I have created one stored procedure for GP calculation It has
>   very long I want to simplify some calculations code.

```
SELECT 25 AS A,35 AS B, SUM(A+B) AS C
```

I know syntax is wrong but I want like below

```
|  A  |  B  |  C  |
|  25 |  35 |  60 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either store values in the temp table.

```
SELECT A, 
       B, 
       Sum(A + B) C 
FROM   (SELECT 25 AS A, 35 AS B) AS TempTable;
```